# how to pass php string code to html

Tags: php, html

i have a function which returns me selected drop down value which obviously coming from DB. problem here is that html of that drop down of mine is existing in php tags as given bellow

```
<?php function _callback_request_type($value, $primary_key)
   {
            //$q=($value == "") ? "selected=selected" : ""; 
           return '<select name="request_type" id="request_type">
                             <option value="">Request Type</option>
                             <option value="Housing" ($value == "Housing") ? "selected=selected" : "" >Housing</option>
                             <option value="Employment" >Employment</option>
                             <option value="Education" >Education</option>
                             <option value="Finance" >Finance</option>
                             <option value="Welfare" >Welfare</option>
                             <option value="Other" >Other</option>
                           </select>';

   } ?>
```

Problem is here that it doesn't give me back any return value , and i get confused now how to put php string values in this html.. all i want is selected dropdown value. please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken your php starting tag is wrong.  The question mark goes before the php, not after.

Comment: @saad Please clarify; as it stands your question is unclear.

Comment: i've changed it to <?php , that was just mitankenly written here by me , no such problem is there in my actual real code. so now come to the actual point please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code a little bit, may work:

```
<?php 
function _callback_request_type($value, $primary_key){
  $q= (!empty($value)) ? "selected=selected" : ""; 

  return 
  '<select name="request_type" id="request_type">
    <option value="">Request Type</option>
    <option value="Housing" '.(($value == "Housing") ? "selected=selected" : "").' >Housing</option>
    <option value="Employment" >Employment</option>
    <option value="Education" >Education</option>
    <option value="Finance" >Finance</option>
    <option value="Welfare" >Welfare</option>
    <option value="Other" >Other</option>
  </select>';

} 

echo _callback_request_type("Housing", null); //Echoes needed stuff.
?>
```