# how to select a specific option when a condition exists

Tags: javascript, php, select

I want to select the specific option in drop down list when a condition is existed.I set the Session in php and if the combo box has the value of `1` , it will be shown the option with value `1`. I mean if session is `1`, select the option with value of `1`, if session is `2`, select the option with vlaue of `2`, and so on... . I want to set automatically select(I see the changes) with session in `php`.
 sth like blewo:

```
<select id="sel" >
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
 <?php $_SESSION['num']='1'; ?>
<script>
  //must be shown the option with value of `1`.
<script>
```

Comment: What's the problem to set the select value? Have you googled?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

```
<select id="sel" >
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
 <?php $_SESSION['num']='1'; ?>
<script>

    //set local variable value so that I don't have to do it for each of the following ways to do this.
    var num =  "<?php echo $_SESSION['num']; ?>";

    //normal javascript 
    document.getElementById("sel").value = num;

    //using jQuery  
    $("#sel").val(num);

<script>
```

Or this try [vikingmaster's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248268/how-to-pass-php-string-code-to-html#answer-17248343)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need js to do this. You can simply use php since you're already grabbing the `num` from the session.
Easiest way to do it would be:

```
<select id="sel" >
    <?php if($_SESSION['num'] == 1): ?>
        <option value='1' selected>one</option>
    <?php else: ?>
        <option value='1'>one</option>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

But if you want to use javascript(jQuery in particular here), you can do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var num = <?php echo $_SESSION['num']; ?>;

        $('#sel > option').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == num){
                $(this).prop('selected', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay2up0jk/).

There are a lot of ways to do this. This is what approach I would take, I'm sure others can provide just as viable or probably better answers.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the value with the selected attribute

```
<select id="sel" >
  <option value='1' selected>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
 <?php $_SESSION['num']='1'; ?>
<script>
  //alternately, set it explicitly
  var element = document.getElementById('sel');
element.value = 1;
<script>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what OP asks for.

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="sel" >
  <option value='1' <?php if($_SESSION['num']=='1') echo "selected"; ?> >one</option>
  <option value='2' <?php if($_SESSION['num']=='2') echo "selected"; ?> >two</option>
  <option value='3' <?php if($_SESSION['num']=='3') echo "selected"; ?> >three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is really a bulky way to achieve the result. OP's mentioned they can use JS, why not to do that?